# Getting 'Undefined property' Error while sending email in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-5.4

I am using default Auth of`Laravel 5.4`. But I am getting this error while sending forgot password email.

```
(1/1) ErrorException
Undefined property: Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage::$cc

in MailChannel.php (line 121)
at HandleExceptions->handleError(8, 'Undefined property: Illuminate\\Notifications\\Messages\\MailMessage::$cc',
```

I am stuck on this stage to launch my app.

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: Could you post the code that's actually throwing the error?

Comment: its default code of laravel auth, any other code you want to see ?

Comment: If you are actually using the laravel boilerplate in an unchanged state then it should work. If you modified or have overridden anything then do share the changes you have made.

Comment: I don't exactly recall making a change on it. Maybe accidentally or unintentionally I have done so. 
Is there any way to check that or any way to replace my boilerplate code ?

Comment: Delete your `vendor` directory and reinstall all your dependencies with `composer install`. That'll fix any accidental changes you made to vendor code.

Answer (score 0):

Try to:

```
use Notification;
```

Instead of:

```
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
```

Comment: thanks for the impromptu response, in which file you want me to make change?

Comment: i guess in: MailChannel.php or in controller where u use it

Comment: If you really want help just say more about problem and errors you get